# Can I use publisher.selectAction from a Visualforce Home Page Component?

Tags: visualforce, home-page-component, publisher-action

I have a Visualforce Home Page Component and a custom Visualforce quick action.

Currently the Home Page Component uses the canvas publisher.js api to publish customActionMessages that the quick action subscribes to.

I have attempted to use the publisher.selectAction from the same Home Page Component, but it does not appear to do anything.

This documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.case_feed_dev.meta/case_feed_dev/case_feed_dev_guide_component_interactions.htm seems to suggest that this functionality is only available from a Custom Console Component. Is this the case and the customActionMessage just happens to work from a Home Page Component, or am I doing something wrong?

Home Page Component:

```
function sendCustomActionMessage() {
    window.Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({
        name: 'publisher.customActionMessage',
        payload: {
            actionName: 'Custom_Action',
            message: 'Do_Something'
        }
    });
}

function selectAction() {
  window.Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({
    name: 'publisher.selectAction',
    payload: {
      actionName: 'Other_Custom_Action'
    }
  });
}
```

The first custom action subscribes to the customActionMessage:

```
window.Sfdc.canvas.publisher.subscribe([{
    name : "publisher.customActionMessage", 
    onData : function(e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
}]);
```